# Microsoft OAuth Is it possible to do incremental authentication with application permissions/scopes?

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am building an app which authenticates via microsoft and needs various that predominantly uses Delegated permissions. I use the v2 auth endpoints to do incremental authentication, only asking for additional scopes when the user needs them.

This has worked well for the many delegated permissions I have so far. In many cases I need admin approval for these permissions, but I have a flow for that which works well.

One of the scopes I have used as a delegated permission is "User.Read.All", I now need the same scope on the application permission level. But I am struggling to work out if there is a way to do incremental authentication for application permissions. The docs say to use the generic endpoint where you don't specify scopes, but this then asks for all the scopes I have on my application registration rather than just passing in the scopes as a param.

Comment: Hi, may I know if your problem was solved ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: No, it turns out what I want to do is not possible with application permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this unfortunately the consent flow allows either a dynamic set of delegated scopes to be submitted or `/.default` which acts like the v1 endpoints and requests all scopes for that client. [See these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent)

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing do with the endpoint and the scopes you specified. Since you use Delegated permissions in your original job, so I consider you use [auth code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) flow or [username/passord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) flow. If we use auth code flow or username/password flow, we can't get application permission when we do authentication although you have assign the application permissions to your registered app. If you want to get application permission when do authentication, you need to use [client credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token) flow instead.

Comment: Sorry these are all about user authentication flow, I need advice re:admin consent which is a separate process

Comment: Hi @RobPethi Yes, my answer is about user authentication flow. But I mean if you use auth code flow or username/password flow(I think you should use one of these flow now), you can't even get application permission application, so we also can't do incremental authentication for application permissions which you mentioned in your requirements.